# AVX-512 Instruction Encoding - {er} Meaning

Tags: assembly, x86, avx, avx512

In the Intel x86 Instruction Set Reference, there are a number of AVX-512 instructions that have an optional {er} in the instruction. For example, one form of VADDPD is defined as

```
EVEX.NDS.512.66.0F.W1 58 /r
VADDPD zmm1 {k1}{z}, zmm2,
zmm3/m512/m64bcst{er}
```

What does the {er} mean?

Comment: {er} means the MXCSR rounding mode can be overridden for the instruction

Comment: What is the syntax for doing this?

Comment: An example `VADDPD  zmm0 {k1},zmm1,zmm3,{rz-sae}` . You can find information and some examples in the [architecture instruction set extensions programming reference](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/c5/15/architecture-instruction-set-extensions-programming-reference.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Intel SDM Volume 2A, 3.1.1.3 " Instruction Column in the Opcode Summary Table":

> {er} — Indicates support for embedded rounding control, which is only applicable to the register-register form
>   of the instruction. This also implies support for SAE (Suppress All Exceptions).

Section 2.6.8 a bit earlier states that {er}, when applicable, can be encoded in EVEX.L´L:

> Static rounding control embedded in the EVEX encoding system applies only to register-to-register flavor of
>   floating-point instructions with rounding semantic at two distinct vector lengths: (i) scalar, (ii) 512-bit. In both
>   cases, the field EVEX.L’L expresses rounding mode control overriding MXCSR.RC if EVEX.b is set. When EVEX.b is
>   set, “suppress all exceptions” is implied. The processor behaves as if all MXCSR masking controls are set.